# Illustrator CS5 do not automatically change the measuring unit to the files default?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, transform, document-setup, units

I am creating images for both web and print so I use pixels (px) and millimeters (mm) back and forth. But whenever I open the other type of file (i.e. opened web(px) first then print(mm), or print(mm) then web(px) ), the units displayed in Transform is always set to the previous file's setting. I have to go to "Document Setup > OK" or  every time I encounter this. It is very frustrating. Is there anyway to fix it, or is it fixed in later versions of Illustrator? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measurement settings are application wide and are not document specific.

Just right-click, or control-click the rulers in the document and choose the scale you want. You can also input *any* scale into measurement fields. If the document is set to use pixels, you can input `50mm` and it will automatically be converted to pixels. There's no need to keep changing preferences.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tip! The problem exist when I need to see the size of shapes in the right units. That would solve it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Try this while in Adobe Illustrator:

**File > New** and then use the "Units" drop-down to select the units you prefer, then click the "OK" button.
[image]